# button doesn't turn disabled when textArea is empty

Tags: java, swing, documentlistener

I added a documentListener to a jTextArea, which should set a button disabled whenever the textArea is empty.
This works just at the starting point when the textArea is empty, but when I type something and then delete all the text until `textArea.getText() == ""`, the button still doesn't turn disabled again.
This is what I wrote:

```
textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

                if (textArea.getText() == null) {
                    disableButton();
                } else {
                    enableButton();
                } 



            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

                if (textArea.getText() == null) {
                    disableButton();
                } else {
                    enableButton();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

                if (textArea.getText() == null) {
                    disableButton();
                } else {
                    enableButton();
                }
            }

            public void enableButton() {
                clearModelMenuItem.setEnabled(true);
                discardModel.setEnabled(true);
                increaseFontSize.setEnabled(true);
                decreaseFontSize.setEnabled(true);
                incMenuItem.setEnabled(true);
                decMenuItem.setEnabled(true); 
            }
```

What is the problem here? 
Thanks for helping!

Comment: change `textArea.getText() == null` to `textArea.getText().isEmpty()`

Comment: `What is the problem here?` - where is your SSCCE like you have been asked for in many of your previous questions??? Where is your debug code that displays the value of the variable that you are testing like you have been asked to do in previous questions? Do your own basic debugging BEFORE posting a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're not actually checking whether the text is empty; you're checking whether it's `null`. There's a difference between a `String` that's empty and a `String` that's `null`.

You need to be checking

```
if ("".equals(textArea.getText())) ...
```

if you want to check whether it's empty.

(You might also want to check for `null`.)